# In MySQL, how to query multiple table counts on column when joining on common columns

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

I have two tables (they come from different original data sources)

Projects (cross sectional data)

```
Timestamp   Project   Owner     Name     Submission_Date
2014-02-18  1         Tim       Susan    2014-02-10
2014-02-18  2         Matt      Jaclyn   2014-02-10
2014-02-18  2         Tim       Mary     2014-02-11
etc
```

and Hitups (activity log)

```
Project  Owner  Name   Hitup_Date
1        Tim    Susan  2014-02-01
2        Matt   Jaclyn 2014-02-02
etc
```

And I want to run a query to get a count of activities from both tables, and grouped by the common project and owner. Given the above totally made up sample data, I'd expect to see results similar to

```
Project    Owner    count(Hitup_Date)   count(Submission_Date)
1          Tim      1                   1
2          Matt     1                   1
2          Tim      null                1
```

My attempt to query this is as follows

```
SELECT p.Project, p.Owner, COUNT(Hitup_Date), COUNT( p.Submission_Date ) 
FROM projects p, hitups h
WHERE p.project = h.project and p.owner = h.owner
AND p.date = ( SELECT MAX( DATE ) FROM projects ) 
GROUP BY p.project, p.owner
```

... which fails miserably. What's going wrong? I've searched exhaustively and have been unable to find prior examples on how to tackle a similar situation explicitly - thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the grouping and aggregation first, and only then join the results:

```
SELECT p.project, p.owner, submission_count, hitup_count
FROM (SELECT   project, owner, COUNT(*) AS submission_count
      FROM     projects
      GROUP BY project, owner) p
LEFT OUT JOIN (SELECT project, owner, COUNT(*) AS hitup_count
               FROM hitups
               GROUP BY project, owner) h 
ON p.project = h.project AND p.owner = h.owner
```

Comment: This worked, and subsequently revealed a few fun issues with the consistency of data between the two sources. Thank you very much.